# How to use an input in python with sql

Tags: python, sql, pycharm, pyodbc

I have this table in Windows Access:

The title of my table is DATA

NAME - GENDER - NUMBER

Jo - Male - 1

Ali - Male - 2

MO - Male - 3

I want to use an input that asks a name and I want my program to give the details of that person.

I tried to do this:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +

        r'DBQ=C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\TennisDatabase.accdb;')
gegevens = conn.cursor()
question = input("Give a name: ")
SelectString = 'SELECT NAME FROM DATA WHERE DATA.NAME = ' + question + ';'

gegevens.execute(SelectString)
gegevensList = gegevens.fetchall()


print(len(gegevensList), "Spelergegevens : ")

for gegevens in gegevensList:
    print (gegevens)
print('')
```

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/Opdracht 1.py", line 9, in 
    gegevens.execute(SelectString)
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I have no clue what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: you can try to insert the query string directly in the gegevens.execute method instead of in a variable. Also try to use '''SELECT NAME FROM DATA WHERE DATA.NAME = question;'''

Comment: well, you are expecting that in `SelectString` the `question` is replaced with the input value. However, the variable call is inside a string and thus you are not actually getting the value. Try `'SELECT NAME FROM DATA WHERE DATA.NAME = ' + question + ';'`. It is not going to solve you main problem but it still needs to be fixed

Comment: I edited you suggestion @jeanggi90 and I tried your suggestion but it does not work unfortunately. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Print out `SelectString` and you will see that it looks something like

```sql
SELECT NAME FROM DATA WHERE DATA.NAME = Gord;
```

Your problem is that `Gord` is not recognized as a string literal; it is interpreted as a column name.

You need to use a *parameterized query*, like this

```python
sql = "SELECT [NAME] FROM [DATA] WHERE DATA.NAME = ?"
crsr.execute(sql, question)
```